# How to use Field Collection in Webform?

Tags: webforms, entities

I want to use field collection module in Webform Component, How can I do that?

Comment: Why would you want to use field collection in a webform? Wouldn't you just group webform inputs in a fieldset?

Comment: If you find yourself building similar webforms again and again, I can see how Field Collection could be a real time saver. On the other hand, if that is the issue, another option is [Node Clone](http://drupal.org/project/node_clone). This lets you clone an existing webform and then make any tweaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did by using entity form + field collection.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to NOT use the Webform module but instead use the [Entityform](https://drupal.org/project/entityform) module and the [Field Collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_addmore provides in certain cases a similar functionality to field collection for Webforms.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, entity collection is better, but can't clone dependancies...can't clone field collections